# Uniform barplot width of plots with different x variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

In two ggplot barplot graphs with different number of x variable, I set the same width of 0.5, but the resulted bars have different actual widths. I think that's due to ggplot is trying to produce same size of figure.

```
library(ggplot2)
x_1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4)
y_1 = c(2, 4, 4, 5)
xy1 = data.frame(matrix(nrow = 4))
xy1$x = x_1
xy1$y = y_1

x_2 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
y_2 = c(14, 3, 5, 3, 2, 4)
xy2 = data.frame(matrix(nrow = 6))
xy2$x = x_2
xy2$y = y_2

plot_1 = ggplot(data = xy1) + 
    geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = x, y = y), stat = "identity", width = 0.5) 
plot(plot_1)

ggsave('1.png')

plot_2 = ggplot(data = xy2) + 
    geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = x, y = y), stat= "identity", width = 0.5) 
plot(plot_2)
ggsave('2.png')
```

As in the figures, one of them has 4 x variables and one has 6 and they have different actual width size.

Is there a approach for me to uniform the width in different plots? Maybe by linking the physical value with actual figure sizes? In that case the ggplot should output figures with different sizes automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the width of the bar gets automatically computed by the `resolution()` of the data (see `?geom_bar`).

Since your x_2 has 1.5 times the amount of x values we can adjust the code for the second plot as follows:

```
plot_2 = ggplot(data = xy2) + 
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = x,y = y), stat = "identity", width = 0.5 * 1.5)
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible if I want to keep both the size and the interval the same for the two figures? which means the second figure should have around 1.5 times larger width than the first one.

Comment: And I just found that using 0.5 * 1.5 won't generate exact the same width, but just a approximate same size. I think that's due to the axis title also taking some space so the ratio is just close to 1.5.

Comment: Yeah you are right it is not perfectly the same. But I sadly do not know how to adjust it 100% correct.

What exactly do you mean by keep both the size and the interval the same? Do you mean the gap between the plots? So the second plot would be wider that the first one?

Comment: I am trying to adjust output size in ggsave. for example for the first one I use height = 10, width = 10, and for the second one I may use height = 10, width = 15 or 14. So the output figures would have roughly the same bar width and interval. But sadly yeah, roughly

Comment: Well you could build the plots without width adjustment and then adjust the width in `ggsave()`.
So it would be `ggsave('1.png', width = 1000, height = 1000, units = "px")` for the first plot and `ggsave('2.png', width = 1500, height = 1000, units = "px")` for the second. But the effect seems to be even more present in this case so you would need to play around with it more.